# Geodesic curves on $S^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> On the unit sphere $S^2$, show that it is not true that the a geodesic curve is the shortest curve between any two points.

The geodesic curves on $S^2$ are great circles. So we can choose an arc $\gamma$ on a great circle such that $\pi<\text{length}(\gamma)<2\pi$, then $\gamma$ is not the shortest curve between two endpoints....

Am I right? Are there any rigorous proofs? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Absolutely right.

Comment: @Michael Hoppe: Thank you!

Comment: You can use spherical coordinates to prove directly that of all paths joining the north pole and a point — say with $\theta = 0$ and $\phi=a$ (using American labels) — the great circle arc is shortest.